# Django LEFT JOIN?

Tags: python, django

I have models, more or less like this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(..)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(.., unique=True)
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, blank=True, related_name='modelbs')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name','modela')
```

I want to do a query that says something like: "Get all the ModelA's where field name equals to X that have a ModelB model with a name of X OR with no model name at all"

So far I have this:

```
ModelA.objects.exclude(field=condition).filter(modelsbs__name=condition)
```

This will get me all the ModelAs that have at least one modelB (and in reality it will ALWAYS be just one) - but if a ModelA has no related ModelBs, it will not be in the result set. I need it to be in the resultset with something like obj.modelb = None

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: On a side note: that'd really help if you used descriptive names like typical Blog/Post scenario or at least Foo/Bar instead of ModelA/ModelB which are non-intuitive and simply hard to read/distinguish.

Answer (score 11):

Use Q to combine the two conditions:

```
from django.db.models import Q
qs = ModelA.objects.exclude(field=condition)
qs = qs.filter(Q(modelbs__name=condition) | Q(modelbs__isnull=True))
```

To examine the resulting SQL query:

```
print qs.query.as_sql()
```

On a similar query, this generates a LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE (a.val = b OR a.id IS NULL).

Comment: It's not making a difference for me

Comment: If all you're going to say is "it's not working", I certainly can't help you.  Did you even examine the SQL?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry I was not more specific I was busy trying a suggestion I found elsewhere. Anyhow, doing what you have is making the join condition be on the where clause as opposed to the ON clause, I'm not exactly sure why but this makes the left join not behave as expected. If I manually run the same query with the condition moved to the ON it works as I want.

Comment: This solved my issue. I was running some conditions plus my Q | Q all in one go, which wasn't working because of the conflict between isnull and the joined table, but adding the Q clause as a filter afterwards got me what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are coming up against the 80% barrier. Why not just use [`.extra(select={'has_x_or_none':'(EXISTS (SELECT ...))'})`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) to perform a subquery? You can write the subquery any way you like and should be able to filter against the new field. The SQL should wind up looking something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
  ((EXISTS (SELECT * FROM other WHERE other.id=primary.id AND other.name='X'))
    OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM other WHERE other.id=primary.id))) AS has_x_or_none
  FROM primary WHERE has_x_or_none=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this patch for custom joins: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7231

Answer (score -3):

LEFT JOIN is a union of two queries.  Sometimes it's optimized to one query.  Sometimes, it is not actually optimized by the underlying SQL engine and is done as two separate queries.

Do this.

```
for a in ModelA.objects.all():
    related = a.model_b.set().all()
    if related.count() == 0:
        # These are the A with no B's
    else:
        # These are the A with some B's
```

Don't fetishize about SQL outer joins appearing to be a "single" query.

Comment: This is years old, but I want to note, terrible advice. This ends up running a huge number of queries behind the scenes, and can easily bring your site to a crawl.