# How can we perform left without foreign key in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have 4 models in django as follows, I am facing problem in left join because there is not foreign key.

```py
class A(Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=False, null=False)
    col2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=False, null=False)
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = "A"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['col1','col2'], name='UX_Col1Col2'),
        ]
```

```py
class B(Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    ...
    class Meta:

        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["col1"], name='UX_col1'),
        ]
```

```py
class C(Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    col1 = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    col2 = models.ForeignKey(D, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    ...
```

```py
class D(Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    col1 = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    ...
```

Now my sql query is

```sql
    SELECT (some columns) from B 
    inner join C on B.id=C.id
    inner join D on D.id=D.id
    left join A on A.col=B.col and A.col=C.Col
```

I am facing problem while doing left join I am doing like this

```py
B.objects.select_related('C','D')
```

How can I do left join

Comment: I don't think you can manage to emulate a left join with Django ORM if you don't have ForeignKey in your `A` model. Maybe you will have to writre a custom SQL query (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: What if I add foreignkey because still I am not able to perform left join

Comment: If you add foreign keys in `A`model, maybe you could use `Q` object like suggested in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419596/8439435